# Nested list or Var list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Im trying to make a nested list work but the problem is that whenever i append a variable it is the same as the first one.

```
array = [[1,0]]
index = 1
for stuff in list:
    array.insert(0,array[0])
    array[0][0]+=1
    index += 1
    if index == 5:
        break
print(array)
```

This returns [[5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0]]

The weird thing is if i were to make the list into a int it would work.

```
array = [1]
index = 1
for stuff in array:
    array.insert(0,array[0])
    array[0]+=1
    index += 1
    if index == 5:
        break
print(array)
```

This one returns [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

For the program i am writing i need to remember two numbers. Should i just give up on making it a list or should i make it into two ints or even a tuple? Also is it even possible to do with lists?

I changed list into array same concept though

Comment: Don't use inbuilt key names as your variable name. This will lead to code inconsistency and unexpected behavior of program.

Comment: list.insert(index, list[0][:])

Comment: yea srry my code is list.insert(0,list[0]) not list.insert(list[0]) made a typo

Comment: And also don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks it worked once i put in the [:]

Comment: ok ill change that too

Comment: Thanks so much! i spent a hour trying to fix it

Comment: [:] is a shallow copy of the list. Which is not a good practice to use in this kind of scenario. You can achieve this in more simpler way. Try to rewrite your function. Cheers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of this line

```
    list.insert(list[0])
```

This always refers the list[0] and refereed in all the inserts which you did in the for loop.

And list of integers and list of lists, behave differently.

Also, mention your expected output.

Comment: list.insert(0, list[0][:]) use this line instead of yours

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up with an explanation from the docs:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
>   bindings between a target and an object.

So whenever you want to copy objects that contain other objects, like your list contains integers or how a class may contain other members, you should know about this difference (also from the docs):

> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the    extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>     the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

To achieve a deep copy, as you tried to do in this situation, you can either use Python's built-in list copy method, if you're on Python 3.3 or higher:

`deepcopy = list.copy()`

Or use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html) module for lower Python versions, which includes a copy.deepcopy() function that returns a deep-copy of a list (or any other compound object).